# session state in suave

Tags: f#, suave

I want to use session state in my Suave project.

I enable the session state for the "/home" url, and following this, I check that this state exists:

```
#r @"packages\Suave.0.32.0\lib\net40\Suave.dll"

open Suave                 // always open suave
open Suave.Http.Successful // for OK-result
open Suave.Web            // for config 
open Suave.Http
open Suave.State.CookieStateStore
open Suave.Http.Applicatives
open Suave.Types

[ 
    path "/home" >>= statefulForSession >>= context  (fun x ->
                match HttpContext.state x with
                | Some state -> OK "session found"
                | None -> Suave.Http.RequestErrors.BAD_REQUEST "No Session Found"
            )]
|> choose
|> startWebServer defaultConfig
```

Every time accessing "/home", it ends with BAD_REQUEST "No Session Found".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like the dll I was using has a flaw, just tried with version 0.28 and it works..

Comment: Yes, as soon as we were made aware of this issue, we fixed it in a one hour, so the latest versions should also be fine :)

Comment: Thx Henrik. Awesome work, I really like what you do. Keep up with the good projects you are creating...